# Typescript regular expression for key to type

Tags: typescript, types

I have the following interface which I want to have more generic, because it contain more localized names like e.g.: `name:en` etc.

```
export interface OsmNames {
  name: string;
  'name:de': string;
  'name:pl': string;
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Is it possible to have a regular expression or something else to define a more generic type?

Answer (score 1):

You can intersect `{ name: string }` with another type that uses a template literal index signature:

```
type OsmNames = { name: string } & { [key: `name:${string}`]: string };
```

Example usage:

```
const osm = {
  name: "",
  'name:de': "",
  'name:pl': "",
} satisfies OsmNames; // okay
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gzgWwHIEMETlAvFA3lAOzQgC4o5gAnASwIHMoBfKAMjygG0BrCEMgAyLoSAElwUa9RvwC6ZCbQaMA3AChVAYwD2BClC2JseVVELEyAIgsAaE1ADkQ0gBMI9yzbuPzYADbuoK1tmOBRgajgAM2oMWERUdDg1IA)

But be aware that this allows keys like `name:whatever` where the part after `name` is not two characters. If you want to limit this to two characters that are lowercase english letters, it's also possible:

```
type Letter = "a" | "b" | "c" | "d" | "e" | "f" | "g" | "h" | "i" | "j" | "k" | "l" | "m" | "n" | "o" | "p" | "q" | "r" | "s" | "t" | "u" | "v" | "w" | "x" | "y" | "z";

type OsmNames = Partial<{ name: string } & Record<`name:${Letter}${Letter}`, string>>;

const osm = {
  name: "",
  'name:de': "",
  'name:pl': "",
} satisfies OsmNames; // still okay
```

However, this prevents us from using an index signature, so we have to use a mapped type (Record does the same thing here). It also looks like [OSM names](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Multilingual_names) span more than just 2 english lowercase letters, so I don't think you want this anyways.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMhzAgJygXigIgIYagH0wCNcCMBjEzAE0owloDNaBzWgC1oEtaArWga1oAbWgFtaAO1oB7WmFoBHWkloBnWsFoBXWgDdaAd1oAPWiFoAvDAG4AULdCQoAeVWiAcllERVaKAAUsJGBOLCEAHgBvKAkvCAAuKFVgJE4JZigAXygAMigAJQgyaSQqcIADWO94gBJIuARkTLqGxCRM8oAaJJS05gA+frtbYolkqGk3P0jbKBi4xIwMTtmoAHIqhKoINcXl1Y2FsCFdzH3s1SwQ1QZOHxc3T29VOyA)